# Mass/weight information about stage separation mechanism

Tags: rockets, mass, stage-separation

How can I get mass/weight information about rocket stage separation mechanisms that are used in multi-stage rockets?

I plan to create an excel table to compare stage separation mechanisms by weight and type(pyro, pneumatic, frangible joint etc.) but to do so I'll need to locate sources of information.

- Are there known sources where these might have been already tabulated or at least compared?
- What other sources and strategies might I use to collect this kind of information?

Comment: But what about strength? What axial and radial could be tolerated?

Comment: It's a good question. I've added a bit to make it clearer to readers that you are not asking for a list, but only asking for search strategies and a few resources. "list questions" asking for lists as answers are discouraged, but this is not one of those. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: I'm guessing these are all highly proprietary to the launch vehicle manufacturer.  For old NASA vehicles you may be able to get something by dumpster diving historical Saturn records and the like.